Not able to unpivot sharepiont columns in a separate table in Power Bi
In Power BI I have a sharepiont list as table and When I tried to "Unpivot Only Selected Columns" then it is not creating separate table. it is unpivot rows in the same dateaset which means rows increased by (No of rows * unpivot columns)
